# Using requirejs to load React Components with a parent/child relationship

Tags: javascript, plugins, module, requirejs, reactjs

I am working on a highly pluggable UI using React/Flux, and loading modules with RequireJS.

I couldn't get around this problem, likely due to my poor knowledge of RequireJS. There is another layer of indirection, but the root of the problem is this:

I have React component A in a module with the following render function:

```
render: function() {

<div>
    <Component B />
</div>
}
```

and component B, in a separate module would be something simple like:

```
render: function() {

    <div> Some Text </div>
}
```

In my top-level module that I dive into with requirejs, I can get componentA like this:

```
require(['ComponentA'], function(ComponentA) {
    React.render(React.createElement(ComponentA,document.getElementById('main'));

});
```

This works great, until I try and use ComponentB in the render function of ComponentA...componentA naturally has no idea what ComponentB is, but I'm not sure of the right approach or how to require ComponentB before componentA tries to render.

Note: I'm converting all the JSX to plain JS beforehand, so that shouldn't be a factor.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your modules are not definitions - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep

Using definitions, ComponentA can absolutely get a reference to ComponentB, simplest example is something like this:

ComponentA - Has Dependencies - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep

```
define(['path/to/ComponentB'], function (ComponentB) {
    return React.createClass( {
        render: function () {
            <div>
                <ComponentB />
            </div>
        }
    });
});
```

ComponentB - No Dependencies - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#deffunc

```
define(function () {
    return React.createClass( {
        render: function () {
            <div>
                Some Text
            </div>
        }
    });
});
```

You can then render ComponentA in your top-level as you mentioned in the question, and ComponentA will contain a ComponentB